# Understanding django loaddata or right way to dumpdata for fixutes

Tags: python, django

I have serialized 4 apps from my project with manage.py dumpdata. But when I'm trying to load it in test as a fixture - i'm getting "Validation Error : This value must be True or False".

How to understand, which line of dump is wrong? Or in which model I got this error?

UPD:
Problem is coming from invalid fixture. But I can't understand, why django dumbdata creates invalid fixtures.

I have added

```
   print field.name
```

in django.core.serializers.python and found invalid values manually. But it's not good way.

UPD.
I'm still interested in a way to dump data for any model and reuse it in tests as a fixture. I'm using postgresql for development.

Comment: And this is one of the reasons why I don't like using SQLite with Django, even for development.

Comment: You'll need to provide more data: what is the model field? What is the json that comes out of it? Now "a fixture" gives an error and "all the serializers are thus wrong". When in fact they normally work, so you'll have to show a real example :-)

Comment: For example, you can try to serialize decimal field.. I will provide detailed example of input/output a little bit later.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all are you using any custom/3rd party Fields?

Although if you did and django's dumpdata couldn't serialize it, it
would raise an exception I suppose. Anyway since last time I checked there
was not any sufficient documentation for writing a custom django serializer,
here is an example for serializing a custom UUIDField:

```
from django.core.serializers.python import Serializer as PythonSerializer
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

class CustomJSONEncoder(DjangoJSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, uuid.UUID):
            return obj.hex
        return super(CustomJSONEncoder, self).default(obj)

class Serializer(PythonSerializer):
    internal_use_only = False
    def end_serialization(self):
        json.dump(self.objects, self.stream, cls=CustomJSONEncoder, **self.options)

    def getvalue(self):
        if callable(getattr(self.stream, 'getvalue', None)):
            return self.stream.getvalue()
```

Then in your settting.py add

```
SERIALIZATION_MODULES = { 'myjson' : 'path.to.my.module.with.serializer' }
```

Then from your shell you can do

```
python manage.py dumpdata --format myjson > myfixtures.myjson # the extension is important!
```

You can load it with

```
python manage.py loaddata myfixtures.myjson
```

Strangely enough `loaddata` does not accept a "format" parameter like dumpdata. It decides the format based on the file extension. Yet I could not find a way to 
hook my custom encoder, so I had to write a "new" serializer :(

That's what I did months ago when I needed to write a custom serializer and
I had to dig through the django's source code to figure it out, since
the official docs had nothing on the subject. I hope it provides some help.

Comment: Slightly better: instead of `'myjson'`, just use `'json'` to overwrite the default one. You won't need to do `--format myjson` anymore!

Comment: @DavidArcos that's not necessarily what you want though, since overriding that JSON serializer globally may have unintended consequences.

Answer (score -3):

try to use json validators, such as this one: http://jsonlint.com/